# How to add a NPM package to Remix route file

Tags: reactjs, react-select, remix.run

Following the [Remix GOTCHA file](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/gotchas#server-code-in-client-bundles), I'm trying to add a npm package to a route file. In this case we are adding `React-select`. Importing the package directly in the route file doesn't work, so we create a util file to handle exporting the package.

We should add the package like this:

```js
import Select from 'react-select'

<Select options={[{ label: "label", value: "value" }]} />
```

In the REMIX application, we will try to add the package from a utils file.

**utils/select.server.ts**

```js
export * from 'react-select';
```

Then we import this in the route folder

**routes/index.tsx**

```js
import * as Select from '~/utils/react-select.server';

<Select options={options} />
```

Resulting in the following error in the browser

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

And this one in the editor

> JSX element type 'Select' does not have any construct or call signatures

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I mis-understand something, but I don't believe that you need to use the utils/select.server.ts file at all.

Did you get the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')` when you tried importing directly?

Based on reading https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select I believe this package is meant to be used directly from client code, so if it's throwing errors due to referencing node code in the client, I'd be surprised.

Importing directly in the client should work:

**routes/index.tsx**

```
import Select from 'react-select'

<Select options={options} />
```

Again, my apologies if you've already tried importing directly.

Comment: For sure, naming that file *.server.ts will not improve things, since such files are not included while making the client bundle.